# Cannot select a record in Global address book addresses by NON SysAdm user

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Opening a Home/Common/Global address book **Global address book** form I get this error

> Cannot create a record in Global address book (DirPartyTable). Party
>   ID: ******, ***. The record already exists.

With my user (is not sysADM) I'm NOT able to select a record in CompanyInfo.
I done a debug ([Debug-NO_SysADM](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/mafsarkhan/posts/debugging-in-dynamics-ax-2012-as-a-non-admin-role)), my user is not able to get a record in *ComanyInfo* by this query

```
select companyInfo 
where companyInfo.DataArea = _currentCompany_
```

This query NOT get an helpful record, but actually the record in CompanyInfo Table exist.

There is any parameter to exclude some roles/user to check-find record in this table? Or there is any way to justify this.

Thanks

Comment: You should not select CompanyInfo by DataAreaId, because it does that by default. There can be only one CompanyInfo for the current company.